# Email wordpress E_Errors

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami, zoho

I am using wordpress and my wordpress is unable to send email I am getting some errors. Below is the errors could anyone help me in this.

## Error Details

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 237 of the file /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/zoho-mail/zohoMail.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/zoho-mail/zohoMail.php:237
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): zmail_integ_settings_callback('')
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(254): do_action('toplevel_page_z...')
#4 {main}
thrown

Answer (score -1):

you send object instead of an array to the zoho plugin